# Allure results is going to AppData\local

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, allure, nunit-3.0

I'm using NUNIT 3 and to create report file I'm trying to use Allure (to C# and NUNIT).

My problem is that the folder **allure-results** is going to:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local>
```

My allureConfig.json has:

```
{
    "allure": {
        "directory": "..\\allure-results",
        "title": "custom run title"
    }
}
```

Note that I used `..\\` to be possible to find in the folder \bin\Debug of the project. But all times when I run the tests, the folder is updated in AppData\Local.

I believe that it is necessary to do some configuration in NUnit, but I don't have any idea what I need to do.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: As shows in github(https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp#configuration): you can set ALLURE_CONFIG environment variable to the full path of json config file to specify config file location(https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/blob/bdf11bd3e1f41fd1e4a8fd22fa465b90b68e9d3f/Allure.Commons.NetCore.Tests/AllureConfigTests.cs#L13-L15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a lot of things on google, the conclusion to solve this problem is:

You need to run **nunit3-console** to run your DLL tests, in this case, the **nunit3-console will save the folder allure-results** in the directory that you want.

For some reason (that nobody on google could explain) NUNIT in Visual Studio doesn't permit that an unknown folder is saved in the \bin\debug project directory.

Then do:

**configure allureConfig.json**:

```
{
    "allure": {
        "directory": "..\\..\\allure-results",
        "title": "a title that you want"
    }
}
```

**configure allureConfig.json to be copied always in output Directory (\bin\Debug)**

[image]

**add Allure in your Test Class**

```
[TestFixture]
[AllureNUnit]
public class MyBeautifulTest
{
}
```

**Run your tests via Visual Studio + NUnit Test Runner**

[image]

**Run your tests via nunit3-console**

```
PS C:\Projetcs\MyProjectAPITest\MyProjectAPITest\bin\Debug> nunit3-console.exe MyProjectAPITest.dll
```

**See your tests results in allure-results (project folder) and run with allure serve**

```
PS C:\Projetos\MyProjectAPITest\MyProjectAPITest> allure serve allure-results\
Generating report to temp directory...
Report successfully generated to
```

**Be happy, in your Pipeline everything will work**

:D